# Looking for a pythonic way to find all swap possibilities in nested list

Tags: python, swap, nested-lists

I'm looking for a way to elegantly generate all the possible "swaps" within the boundaries of a list of lists. I need to check for a certain list with multiple routes, what the swapping of two cities would do for the total length of that route list. All the cities are represented by integer numbers. Consider this example:

```
route_list = [[0, 7, 40, 41, 96, 34, 75, 127, 48, 65, 79, 27, 126, 78, 0],
              [0, 56, 45, 2, 67, 66, 59, 124, 82, 133, 102, 54, 57, 0]]
```

Every day, the route starts at 0 (Which is the integer that represents the HQ-location) and ends there as well. What I need is list with all the possible swaps. I've indicated the swaps that have to be done with ** ** so expected output would be:

```
all_possible_swaps =

[[0, **40**, **7**, 41, 96, 34, 75, 127, 48, 65, 79, 27, 126, 78, 0],
 [0, 56, 45, 2, 67, 66, 59, 124, 82, 133, 102, 54, 57, 0]],

[[0, **41**, 40 ,**7**, 96, 34, 75, 127, 48, 65, 79, 27, 126, 78, 0],
 [0, 56, 45, 2, 67, 66, 59, 124, 82, 133, 102, 54, 57, 0]],

[[0, **96**, 40 ,41, **7**, 34, 75, 127, 48, 65, 79, 27, 126, 78, 0],
 [0, 56, 45, 2, 67, 66, 59, 124, 82, 133, 102, 54, 57, 0]],
```

Up untill

```
[[0, **57**, 40 ,41, 96, 34, 75, 127, 48, 65, 79, 27, 126, 78, 0],
 [0, 56, 45, 2, 67, 66, 59, 124, 82, 133, 102, 54, **7**, 0]],
```

Then, for the first element in the route (Which is 7 in this case) all possible "swaps" have been exhausted. Then the code should move on to the next element, 40 in this case, and do all possible swaps with the element 40.

I've been breaking my head over this for the last couple days, and I can only come up with a solution that has a quadruple for-loop. I have the feeling this can be done much more elegantly, since swapping array elements is such a basic part of any programming language. Does anyone know a **pythonic** solution for this problem?

Comment: Close vote without a comment is pointless, I believe I am pretty specific in my problem description so do not agree with the question needing "more focus"

Comment: If you always assume that `0` is the first and the last element, aren't you effectively looking for all combinations of the entries within (i.e. `itertools.permutations`)? Or are you only looking at what a single swap of cities would get you in efficiency? And how do you want to handle 7 swapping with 40 .. and then 40 swapping with 7?

Comment: I need to check for *all* possible city swaps. Also city swaps *between* lists are allowed. The only restriction is basically that all routes start at 0 and end at 0. I have taken a look at the itertools functions, but wasn't able to implement them. Something with itertools.permutations could possibly solve my problem, but I would need to strip the 0's from the list?

Comment: Yes, permutate the list given by `route_list[1:-1]` - it should give you all the different combinations of travel routes through the cities (.. and it'll be a lot!). Swapping between lists is another problem again, in effect you're looking at the permutation space of _all cities_, then subsectioned off into most equal (I'm guessing) travel distance for the lists to distribute the load across the drivers?

Comment: Yes, I need to swap between the lists. Basically, I'm implementing a "move and swap" algorithm, and i need *all* the possible swaps, because I want to find the swap that gives me the best improvement in total driving distance, for all the routes combined.

Comment: I was thinking maybe something like: `def swapPositions(route_list, pos1, pos2):
    route_list[pos1], route_list[pos2] = route_list[pos2], route_list[pos1]
    return route_list` or use permutations but then I would need to flatten the list, and I don't want to flatten the list because then it's hard to re-obtain the original routers. Long story short: I'm stuck.

Comment: Sounds like you have to start by defining your problem better - allowing for arbitrary number of list swaps in effect means that you can flatten the list and redistribute (i.e. insert the 0's) the route lists at any point

Comment: I just need all the possible swaps, so not an arbitrary number of list swaps, I need all the possibilities of swapping, say element 7 to every other position in every other list, and then continue and do this for all elements.

Answer (score 1):

itertools.permutations is a nice function which helps you return all possible options of the list. stripping the 0's (startingpoints) of the beginning and end of the list produces the following hypothetical `routelist`
This might help you:

```
import itertools

routelist = [5, 8, 52, 16, 87]

matrix = list(itertools.permutations(routelist, 5))

print(matrix)
```

output:

```
[(5, 8, 52, 16, 87), (5, 8, 52, 87, 16), (5, 8, 16, 52, 87), (5, 8, 16, 87, 52), (5, 8, 87, 52, 16), (5, 8, 87, 16, 52), (5, 52, 8, 16, 87), (5, 52, 8, 87, 16), (5, 52, 16, 8, 87), (5, 52, 16, 87, 8), (5, 52, 87, 8, 16), (5, 52, 87, 16, 8), (5, 16, 8, 52, 87), (5, 16, 8, 87, 52), (5, 16, 52, 8, 87), (5, 16, 52, 87, 8), (5, 16, 87, 8, 52), (5, 16, 87, 52, 8), (5, 87, 8, 52, 16), (5, 87, 8, 16, 52), (5, 87, 52, 8, 16), (5, 87, 52, 16, 8), (5, 87, 16, 8, 52), (5, 87, 16, 52, 8), (8, 5, 52, 16, 87), (8, 5, 52, 87, 16), (8, 5, 16, 52, 87), (8, 5, 16, 87, 52), (8, 5, 87, 52, 16), (8, 5, 87, 16, 52), (8, 52, 5, 16, 87), (8, 52, 5, 87, 16), (8, 52, 16, 5, 87), (8, 52, 16, 87, 5), (8, 52, 87, 5, 16), (8, 52, 87, 16, 5), (8, 16, 5, 52, 87), (8, 16, 5, 87, 52), (8, 16, 52, 5, 87), (8, 16, 52, 87, 5), (8, 16, 87, 5, 52), (8, 16, 87, 52, 5), (8, 87, 5, 52, 16), (8, 87, 5, 16, 52), (8, 87, 52, 5, 16), (8, 87, 52, 16, 5), (8, 87, 16, 5, 52), (8, 87, 16, 52, 5), (52, 5, 8, 16, 87), (52, 5, 8, 87, 16), (52, 5, 16, 8, 87), (52, 5, 16, 87, 8), (52, 5, 87, 8, 16), (52, 5, 87, 16, 8), (52, 8, 5, 16, 87), (52, 8, 5, 87, 16), (52, 8, 16, 5, 87), (52, 8, 16, 87, 5), (52, 8, 87, 5, 16), (52, 8, 87, 16, 5), (52, 16, 5, 8, 87), (52, 16, 5, 87, 8), (52, 16, 8, 5, 87), (52, 16, 8, 87, 5), (52, 16, 87, 5, 8), (52, 16, 87, 8, 5), (52, 87, 5, 8, 16), (52, 87, 5, 16, 8), (52, 87, 8, 5, 16), (52, 87, 8, 16, 5), (52, 87, 16, 5, 8), (52, 87, 16, 8, 5), (16, 5, 8, 52, 87), (16, 5, 8, 87, 52), (16, 5, 52, 8, 87), (16, 5, 52, 87, 8), (16, 5, 87, 8, 52), (16, 5, 87, 52, 8), (16, 8, 5, 52, 87), (16, 8, 5, 87, 52), (16, 8, 52, 5, 87), (16, 8, 52, 87, 5), (16, 8, 87, 5, 52), (16, 8, 87, 52, 5), (16, 52, 5, 8, 87), (16, 52, 5, 87, 8), (16, 52, 8, 5, 87), (16, 52, 8, 87, 5), (16, 52, 87, 5, 8), (16, 52, 87, 8, 5), (16, 87, 5, 8, 52), (16, 87, 5, 52, 8), (16, 87, 8, 5, 52), (16, 87, 8, 52, 5), (16, 87, 52, 5, 8), (16, 87, 52, 8, 5), (87, 5, 8, 52, 16), (87, 5, 8, 16, 52), (87, 5, 52, 8, 16), (87, 5, 52, 16, 8), (87, 5, 16, 8, 52), (87, 5, 16, 52, 8), (87, 8, 5, 52, 16), (87, 8, 5, 16, 52), (87, 8, 52, 5, 16), (87, 8, 52, 16, 5), (87, 8, 16, 5, 52), (87, 8, 16, 52, 5), (87, 52, 5, 8, 16), (87, 52, 5, 16, 8), (87, 52, 8, 5, 16), (87, 52, 8, 16, 5), (87, 52, 16, 5, 8), (87, 52, 16, 8, 5), (87, 16, 5, 8, 52), (87, 16, 5, 52, 8), (87, 16, 8, 5, 52), (87, 16, 8, 52, 5), (87, 16, 52, 5, 8), (87, 16, 52, 8, 5)]
```

Comment: Permutations is a great start but I would need a way to apply this *between* lists as well